# Plotting response variable against two predictor vars

Tags: r, statistics, response

Can someone help me figure out the R code for 2 predictor vars on x/y-axes with the plot data being the response variable?

I tried plot(Response ~ P1 | P2....)

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, unless you're talking about some 3D plot where the response is depth? If you have P1 and P2 and put P1 on the x and P2 on the y then you're going to be marking the co-ordinates of those points and 'response' won't come into it at all.

Comment: I admit I'm a little lost on this one. My understanding is that I can plot P1 on one axis, P2 on the other and the response as varying sizes reflecting the relationship to P1 and P2.

Comment: Ah right, you want something like this http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_point.html, the 6th plot down? If so that page should help you, otherwise you'll have to use dput() on your data.frame or something so people can see the exact nature of your data to help you further.

Comment: you need a third dimension to your plot, whether it's colour, size, shape, intensity, or faceting is always an option. Click around on the ggplot website for some other good ideas. If you get stuck, come back with data and a specific question. Good luck!

Comment: never mind - it's plot(x, y, cex = z)

Comment: good! you can post it as an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 1):

You can plot a "3rd dimension" with contourplot or levelplot. Once you have the data as a data.frame with those column names, it would be done as:

```
require(lattice)
contourplot(Response ~ P1 + P2, data=dfrm)
```

Your comment indicates that you want size to be the "3rd dimension" so you would also want to look at:

```
require(sp)
?bubble
```